# If $T$ is unitary then $T(A^\perp)=T(A)^\perp$

Tags: hilbert-spaces

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $A(\neq \emptyset)\subset H$. If $T\in BL(H)$ is unitary, then $$T(A^\perp)=T(A)^\perp.$$

Let $y\in T(A^\perp)\implies \exists x\in A^\perp\ \text{s.t}\ T(x)=y. $ Since, $x\in A^\perp\implies \forall\ a\in A,\ \langle x,a\rangle=0$.

Since $T$ is unitary, implies $TT^*=I=T^*T$. 
\begin{align*}
& T(x)=y\\
\implies& T^*T(x)=T^*(y)\\
\implies& T^*(y)=x
\end{align*}
Since, $\langle x,a\rangle=0\implies \langle T^*(y),a\rangle=0$.

Now I'm stuck, what to do. How to proceed further. Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: For all $a \in A$, $$\langle T(x), T(a)\rangle =  \langle x, T^*T(a)\rangle = \langle x , a \rangle =0$$ since $x \in A^\perp$. So, $y = T(x) \in T(A)^\perp$. The converse can be proved similarly. If $y \in T(A)^\perp$, then for all $a \in A$, $$0 = \langle T(a),y \rangle = \langle a, T^*(y) \rangle.$$ Hence $T^*(y) \in A^\perp$ and $y = T(T^* (y)) \in T(A^\perp)$.